# get start and stop of youtube/video playing in webview

Tags: java, android

I was wondering if it possible to get a notification and timestamp  when a video has started to play and stop playing as when it reaches the end of the video when playing from a webview ?

Comment: Googling but couldnt find anything , I know that the omxbuffer loads when video is playing so maybe get a notification when it's loads when the video is pressed start ?

Comment: Anyone have any idea how I can achieve this ?? I just want to know that the video has started and that it has stopped playing. The video is using HTML5